# Same div heights for sidebar and content

Tags: html, css

Assume following html page:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div id="wrapper">
   <div id="header"/>
   <div id="navigation"/>
   <div id="leftcolumn"/>
   <div id="content/>
   <div id="footer"/>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that the leftcolumn div and the content div always have the same height. Sometimes the leftcolumn div is higher than the content div because there is little content and vice versa: when there is a lot of content, the content div is higher than the leftcolumn div.

The situation as it is now produces some lay-out shenanigans because the body background, leftcolumn background and content background are all in a different colour.

This is my CSS as-is:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #FFFEE9;
}

#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 900px;
    height: auto;
}

#content {
    float: left;
    color: #006350;
    background: #DEE3DC;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline;
    width: 730px;
}

#contents {
    margin: 35px;
}

#contents h1, h2 {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#contents p {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#header {
    color: black;
    width: 900px;
    float: left;
    height: 160px;
    background: #FFFEE9;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#navigation p {
    padding: 3px;
}

#footer {
    width: 900px;
    height: 40px;
    clear: both;
    color: white;
    background: #83422D;
    font-size: 80%;
}

#footer a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#footer p {
    padding: 4px;
}

#navigation {
    float: left;
    width: 900px;
    height: 25px;
    color: white;
    background: #83422D;
}

#navigation a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

#navigation a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#leftcolumn {
    color: white;
    background: #006350;
    height: 100%;
    width: 170px;
    float: left;
}

#leftcolumn a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

#leftcolumn a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#leftcolumn li {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#leftcolumn ul {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    list-style: none;
}

.centered {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}

#gallery {
    height: 300px;
    width: 650px;
}

#gallery img {
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#gallerytext {
    width: 400px;
    font-size: 75%;
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 155px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

I've tried using a combination of CSS styles like `height: 100%, height:inherit, height:auto,...` on the different divs (wrapper, leftcolumn and content) but I can't seem to get the result I want. Bottom line: what CSS styles should I use if I want the leftcolumn and content div have the same height, regardless of which one is higher at that time. (And without using javascript please).

JsFiddle example where the leftcolumn is larger: http://jsfiddle.net/CQPnF/4/

Example where the content is larger: http://jsfiddle.net/BQkme/

Comment: Even if it was only for the purpose of the demo, I wouldn't end the div annotation with '/>' as opposed to closing it out with a </div>

Comment: I know, but I couldn't be bothered for this one :p

Comment: @Matthias can you upload the image of your desired result what exactly you want because i have checked its to much messy and its not a proper HTML markup so its better to upload your desired result image as well for quick exact answer of your query.....

Comment: @ShailenderArora: Added JsFiddles

Comment: You can always use javascript /jQuary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your desired results with the use of `display:table-cell` rather `float` in your left and right panels :-

I have removed float from your `#content & #leftcolummn` and gave them `display:table-cell;` and its working fine as per your requirement.

**UPDATED CSS**

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #FFFEE9;
}

#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 900px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#content {
    color: #006350;
    background: #DEE3DC;
    display:table-cell;
    width: 730px;
}

#contents {
    margin: 35px;
}

#contents h1, h2 {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#contents p {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#header {
    color: black;
    width: 900px;
    float: left;
    height: 160px;
    background: #FFFEE9;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#navigation p {
    padding: 3px;
}

#footer {
    width: 900px;
    height: 40px;
    clear: both;
    color: white;
    background: #83422D;
    font-size: 80%;
}

#footer a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#footer p {
    padding: 4px;
}

#navigation {
    float: left;
    width: 900px;
    height: 25px;
    color: white;
    background: #83422D;
}

#navigation a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

#navigation a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#container {
    border:1px solid red;
    overflow:hidden;

}

#leftcolumn {
    color: white;
    background: #006350;
    width: 170px;
    display:table-cell;
}

#leftcolumn a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

#leftcolumn a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#leftcolumn li {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#leftcolumn ul {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    list-style: none;
}

.centered {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}

#gallery {
    height: 300px;
    width: 650px;
}

#gallery img {
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#gallerytext {
    width: 400px;
    font-size: 75%;
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 155px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

see the demo :- http://jsfiddle.net/BQkme/10/

Comment: Nice and clean solution! Works perfectly :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is a teensy bit hacky because you need some supporting markup, but it does work and I have used it before.

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

The main issue I have with it is that you have to nest your content divs to a depth equaling the number of columns. In your case, it's not a huge problem because you'd only be nesting your content inside 2 container divs.

Your markup might end up looking something like the following:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div id="wrapper">
   <div id="header"/>
   <div id="navigation"/>
   <div id="container_content">
     <div id="container_leftcolumn">
       <div id="leftcolumn"/>
       <div id="content/>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div id="footer"/>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Of course, if you're not averse to "faking it" with background images, and your width isn't fluid, you could always create a background image with your desired column structure and repeat-y.

Comment: Oh, I see what you did there. +1 for that, but I'm going to bit more to check out any other solutions that may be coming out.

Comment: No worries. I seem to remember seeing a really awesome solution once upon a time and I told myself to remember it next time the problem came around, but for the life of me, I can't find it now. I'll let you know if I come across anything.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use absolute positioning.

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/CQPnF/)*** is a working Live Demo.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 to this solution. I'd use this over the answer I posted, Matthias.

Comment: Just a caveat - not sure if this works in IE6 (but that hopefully isn't something you need to support).

Comment: Ok, it seems I'm not 100% sure how your fix works exactly.. Could you perhaps elaborate using the real code of the website I'm trying to make this work for? http://jsfiddle.net/CQPnF/4/

Comment: (See my edit for another JsFiddle where the content is larger than the leftcolumn)